# Jquery Removing psuedo element styles - disabling anchor unstyle anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have declared my anchor style like this:

```
.disabledanchor a,
.disabledanchor a:hover,
.disabledanchor a:focus {
color: inherit;
cursor: inherit;
text-decoration: inherit
}
```

What should I pass to the jquery addclass to apply this style?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: I am already doing a $(element).addClass('disabledAnchor') but it does not work. I think it is because of the pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

The class name, of course, `"disabledanchor"`

Comment: @David Thomas — The question is about what argument to give to `addClass`, not to `$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // replace element with Selector/dom element/object/array
    $(element).addClass('disabledanchor');
});
```

Comment: well you should publish more your html